# Checkout to upstream branch

Tags: git, github

How do you checkout an upstream branch on git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your current branch using [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html). If you’ve fetched from your upstream and don’t have a local branch with that name, `git checkout` will create it automatically to track the upstream one of the same name:

```
git checkout <name of the upstream branch>
```

Comment: But then how do I push that branch into my repository?

Comment: @wolfy1339: `git push`?